# Not able to install express via npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, web-development-server

I have been trying to install express through npm in visual studio code but I am consistently getting the following error upon giving the command:

Command:

> npm install express --save

Error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...1.1.tgz"},"engines":{'

Please provide me some help.

Comment: Run this and try install again `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked very well. Just a kind request if you can tell what was the problem and how did this solve it?

Comment: Ok. Please upvote my comment. This is a problem related to npm cache. You get this error if it gets corrupted.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the minimal reputation to upvote your comment. But anyways thanks for the help.